# karate gatling api script works fine with simulation.scala but for error didn't printing logs/ error details in console and gatling report

Tags: karate

Running existing karate script for performance testing with gatling, having 3 endpoint out of which 2 end point are passing and one is getting error, unable to get root cause of failure, no logs in report and in karate log file, And same script passing with all 3 end point with karate execution.
How we can print log and error details in gatling report or console.

karate.log file :
`

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>target/karate.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.intuit" level="DEBUG"/>

<logger name="io.gatling.http.engine.response" level="DEBUG" />
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>
```

`

simulation file :

class testSimulation extends Simulation{
val getUser = scenario("getCall").exec(karateFeature("classpath:xyz.feature")).exec(session => {
System.out.println("*** id in gatling: " + session("id").as[String])
System.out.println("*** session status in gatling: " + session.status)
session
})
setUp(
getUser.inject(rampUsers(1) during(5 seconds))
)
}

**execution command** : mvn clean "-Dkarate.env=sitq" test-compile gatling:test
result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa515.png)
[image]

Comment: highly unlikely anyone other than you can troubleshoot this. one tip is make sure the `logback-test.xml` file is on the test-classpath, it can be either `src/test/java` or `src/test/resources` depending on how your project is set up

Comment: logback-test.xml is present at same location src/test/java. Getting log format not recognized error even though possible log format are enabled in configuration.

Comment: sorry I give up. try to compare your project setup with the examples in the documentation. all the best